# Is it possible to install Mint linux without all third party software?

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint

Or at least customize it.

I want to use it as a development system running on a VM and I don't need Libreoffice, Firefox and most the other stuff in it.

Wanna keep it thin

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply install the default configuration then remove the applications?  The only other alternative is to build it yourself after you remove the applications.

Comment: @Ramhound I could do that, was wondering if there was a painless way of doing it. I guess not.

Comment: Presumably there is  "select software" option, or a "minimal install" when setting up mint? If not, shop around for something a bit more flexible; as you have not-run-of-the-mill requirements, you'll be grateful later.